# Can I carry Mac Mini between home & office daily without damaging the hardware?

Tags: mac-mini

I would like to carry a Mac Mini from home to office daily as I work at both places. Would daily plugging /unplugging have any effect? What extra hardware from Apple would I need to purchase. My office has Windows 8 PCs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The Mac Mini isn't as fragile as the MacBook line and they survive that exact environment quite well.